# How to share files to devices connected between router 1 & router 2

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, file-sharing, ip-address

Hardware:

Huawei HG8247 (router 1) - router & modem combo.

Linksys EA6900 (router 2) - router with 4TB hard drive attached.

Goal:

Share hard drive files to a laptop connected to router 1 via LAN.

Details:

I purchased router 2 so that I could provide access to files in my 4TB HDD to everyone in the house. I need help with setting up router 2 so that a laptop connected on router 1 can access the HDD contents via LAN.

I setup the hardware like this:

Router 1 Ethernet Port > Powerline Adapter A > Powerline Adapter B > Router 2 Internet Port

I have read articles in this site about disabling router 2 DHCP and changing the IP address to something within the DHCP range of router 2. Router 2 will not let me change the IP because it gives me an "Invalid IP address range" error.

Router 1 IP - 192.168.100.1

Router 2 IP - 192.168.1.1

I'm trying to sort this out without messing around with router 1 because I'm afraid that I might screw up the settings that ISP placed on it.

Comment: Put router 2 in bridge mode.

Comment: I'm reading the user guide now to do that.

Comment: It's working now. Thank you @DavidPostill for taking me to the answer. I just did some test now and unfortunately the file transfer speeds are only around 2Mbps.. I was expecting it to be at gigabit speeds. Any suggestions on how to improve it?

Comment: Not all powerline adapters support Gigabit speeds ... but you should get more than 2Mbps.

Comment: The powerline I have is a TP-LINK AV1200 Powerline Adapter and has gigabit speed as advertised. I do get around 35Mbps transfer speeds                                            If I did it on my PC which is connected to router 2 via LAN

Comment: I would ask a new question ...